# HDD disconnects after random intervals on raspberry pi 4

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, usb-drive

I have a 2.5" hard drive connected to my raspberry pi4 usb 3.0 port (it draws power from the raspberry pi).

I have used my drive on windows machines before and had 0 problems. After connecting to the raspberry and mounting the drive, it got disconnected with Device I/O errors (NTFS).

I did chkdsk on windows and had no issues, plugged the drive back in the raspberry and the problems started again.
I formatted it using command line to ext4 and it was fine for an hour or so then it got disconnected with this error when running dmesg

[image]

Is my raspberry pi4 killing my drive? I got it yesterday so it's new.

Comment: **Probably** not enough power to HD.

Comment: I checked with other forms before buying the SATA-usb3.0 connector. Forms say usb ports provide 1.2A. The HDD is rated at 0.58A 5V. I have no other usb ports used. It's a 7200RPM WD Black, this could be the reason for a sudden increase in power draw causing errors?

Comment: Maybe what @lserin says about sleeping could be it. I am just guessing. And I don't think the colour would make it draw more power that the manufacturer states.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a Raspberry 3B. In the end I had two issues:

- power saving. If I read new files once every five minutes no problems. Leave the disk alone half an hour and I would get errors. I remember not being able to find the sleep support in Raspbian (my fault), and finally using `hdparm` to fix the disk, I probably set the sleep time to something really ludicrous.
- excessive power drain. This came out after I plugged the Raspberry into a "UPS" board designed to keep the Raspberry powered for short(ish) periods even if the charger was unplugged. Not always, but I'd say that once every three power disconnects, the disk would quit. **It never happened with the charger plugged in**.

I never had any HDD damage, the HDD was an old, slow 500GB 5400 RPM Toshiba MQ01ABF050.

But to tell you the truth, I am not so sure it was the hard disk (It is rated +5V 1A, so it should drain 5W) rather than the USB adapter. I no longer have that adapter, but I have here both the Pi and the HD, I can run some experiments if needed.

Comment: I did set it to not sleep using hdparm "sudo hdparm -S 0 /dev/sda1 ".  I also kept reading files off the disk but it still disconnected with the same error, the disk did not stop spinning when it was disconnected. P.S I'm a noob.

Comment: @riyadmalakh there are lots of cases like yours. This guy claims to have found a workaround: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=182942 . Others have solved changing USB cables or using a USB 2.0 port. Try that, and a more powerful charger. This might help you pinpoint where the trouble actually lies.

Comment: After few days of following the instructions on the links you've mentioned and troubleshooting, I've managed to solve the problem by simple plugging it into a usb2 port instead.......... thanks, Linux is amazing :)

Comment: Okay, so the bad news -- it is the USB adapter that does not "collaborate" with the Linux code. The good news though is that a different adapter might work!

Comment: I wonder if hooking the hard drive up to a powered USB 3.0 adapter would help things out.